# How to make jquery integer and decimal mask?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have made a mask for my  tag for validating the user input onBlur

```
 unitprmask:/^\d+,\d{1,1}$/,
```

But this mask accepts only 1,1 numbers meaning that there should be at least 1 decimal number, which is not what I want, I want to allow user to enter int numbers too.

The other issue is that it accept comma  in between the 2 numbers like 12,3 but what i need is to force users to input 12.3, use point instead of comma. 
Could you tell me what should I add to my mask or how to change it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Mask Money instead. It's a stable lib.

https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

But, if you want to do this regex, this one works:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/
```

You can see here: http://rubular.com/r/Eh6sNab55u

Comment: The `{1,1}` is useless. And it's better to use a non-capture group `(?: )` instead of a capture group.

Comment: @dap.tci: Ok, so I give you +1.